# click event on jquery, need to loop

Tags: jquery, loops, onclick, jquery-animate

I have a website where, using jQuery, on click a sort of slideshow images change. My problem is that when it gets to the end, more colored spaces appear (without images) and I need for it to "loop"; when it gets to 15, go back to one.

This is what I have for the images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        $("#con-libros").animate({"left": "-=130px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        var current = parseInt($("#con-libros").css('left'))*-1;

        if( current < 0 && current > 1949 ) {
           $("#con-libros").animate({"left": "-=130px"}, "slow");
        }else{
           $("#con-libros").animate({"left": "0px"}, "slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I tred it but somehow didn't work. I tried this though: 


$(document).ready(function(){
 var libro_ancho = 135;
 var libros_total = 15;
 var libros = 1;
 $("body").click(function(){
  
  if (libros == (libros_total-6))
  {
   $("#con-libros").animate({"left": "+="+(libro_ancho*(libros_total-7))+"px"}, "slow");
   libros = 1;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#con-libros").animate({"left": "-="+libro_ancho+"px"}, "slow");
   libros += 1;
  }
  })
 })

and solved it. 

Thanks anyways!